# Typeset assigments +=, -= etc nicely?

Tags: math-operators

Could someone please show me how to get LaTeX to properly typeset the -=, += assignment operators. I have tried

```
$a -= 1$
$a\texttt{-=}1$
$a\verb!-=!1$
```

but they all look really ugly. I have been searching all over to find a solution for this, but apparently I am the only one with this problem. And I only have two such assignments in my whole document, so I am not interested in typesetting arbitrary blocks of C++ code, just those two assignments

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What do you mean with "nicely"? Don't you like the font or the justification?

Comment: I suspect you want to use a package like listings or minted to format computer program source code, particularly in C or C++.

Comment: I second Benjamin McKay. TeX' math mode is for typesetting _maths_. Maths is a declarative language, not an imperative one, therefore assignment operators don't make much sense; if you try to write imperative code as maths equations it's going to become extremely messy because there's no real support for structuring loop constructs etc.. And without such constructs, there's no point in using assignment/modification at all, so if you only have two such assignments in your document, you're simply doing maths wrong, nothing else.

Comment: I'm interested in what type of document you are writing.

Comment: A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user41127".

Answer (score 31):

these two-part operators have to be declared as operators to get the correct spacing
on either side.  the following definitions will take care of that, while forcing each
individual part to be treated as an ordinary character.

```
\newcommand{\pluseq}{\mathrel{{+}{=}}}
\newcommand{\minuseq}{\mathrel{{-}{=}}}
```

the result may still not be to your liking, but if you find the two parts to be
farther apart than you think they should be, that can be adjusted by some negative
space between them.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

I'd propose

```
$a\mathrel{-}=1$
```

[image]

For a general purpose macro, define

```
\newcommand{\assign}[2]{%
  \mathrel{#1}\mathrel{#2}%
}
```

so that you can call

```
$a \assign{-}{=} 1$
$a \assign{=}{+} 1$
$a \assign{++}{=} 1$
```

[image]